# Identification request for anime movie: A boy who loses his parents, fights dinosaurs/monsters and rescues a girl he falls in love with

Tags: shounen-kenya

Please help me find this anime movie that I watched in the 1980s: The story is about a boy who travels with his parents on a holiday to some kind of island, then he gets lost, and has to become brave to survive as he fights these monsters/dinosaurs, and kills them with a long spear (half metal half wooden). He also finds a girl whom he protects/teams up with. In the end, his parents find him again, as a transformed brave boy, and they leave all together with the girl he falls in love with.

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie and not a TV series? Also, can you describe a little more the main characters?

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be **[Shounen Kenya](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/shounen-kenya)**

> This cartoon, based on a popular manga (Japanese-style comic), centers
>   on an 11-year-old boy who goes to Africa with his father in 1941.
>   Because he is Japanese, the father is detained by the British. The boy
>   joins up with a beautiful native girl, and the adventure begins, a
>   sort of Young Indy Jones meets Tarzan.

- The main character has 1/2 wooden 1/2 steel spear.
- He traveled with his parent to a place with dinosaurs.
- He rescue a native girl.

[image]

Comment: This was the first anime movie I watched when I was 6 years old and I've been longing to watch it again but had no idea what the name was, I spent many hours searching for it on Google and going through long lists of anime movies in the 80s, but couldn't find it. Thanks for naming it, I managed to find it now on youtube, the story remains ever so powerful in my mind! I will enjoy rewatching this tonight after 30 years! I tried to vote for your answer but it didn't let me as I'm new to this website, don't know how to mark the answer as answered. But many thanks to you, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user13089 Please have a look at [this page](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), as you seem to have created a second account by mistake. Do not hesitate to contact me or [another mod](http://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) if you experience any more issues.